# create and insert into database tables using luigi

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy, luigi

I am trying to understand the correct way to drop and recreate a table and insert data into the newly created table using luigi. I have multiple CSV files passed from the prior task to the task which should be inserted into the database.

My current code looks like this.

```
class CreateTables(sqla.CopyToTable):
connection_string = DatabaseConfig().data_mart_connection_string
table = DatabaseConfig().table_name

def requires(self):
    return CustomerJourneyToCSV()

def output(self):
    return SQLAlchemyTarget(
        connection_string=self.connection_string,
        target_table="customerJourney_1",
        update_id=self.update_id(),
        connect_args=self.connect_args,
        echo=self.echo)

def create_table(self, engine):

    base = automap_base()
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    metadata = MetaData(engine)

    base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

    # Drop existing tables
    for i in range(1, len(self.input())+1):
        for t in base.metadata.sorted_tables:
            if t.name in "{0}_{1}".format(self.table, i):
                t.drop(engine)

    # Create new tables and insert data
    i = 1
    for f in self.input():
        df = pd.read_csv(f.path, sep="|")
        df.fillna(value="", inplace=True)

        ts = define_table_schema(df)

        t = Table("{0}_{1}".format(self.table, i), metadata, *[Column(*c[0], **c[1]) for c in ts])

        t.create(engine)

        # TODO: Need to remove head and figure out how to stop the connection from timing out
        my_insert = t.insert().values(df.head(500).to_dict(orient="records"))

        session.execute(my_insert)

        i +=1

    session.commit()
```

The code works creates the tables and inserts the data but falls over with the following error.

```
C:\Users\simon\AdviceDataMart\lib\site-packages\luigi\worker.py:191: 
DtypeWarning: Columns (150) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import 
or set low_memory=False.
  new_deps = self._run_get_new_deps()
File "C:\Users\simon\AdviceDataMart\lib\site-packages\luigi\worker.py", line 
191, in run
new_deps = self._run_get_new_deps()
File "C:\Users\simon\AdviceDataMart\lib\site-packages\luigi\worker.py", line 
129, in _run_get_new_deps
task_gen = self.task.run()
File "C:\Users\simon\AdviceDataMart\lib\site-
packages\luigi\contrib\sqla.py", line 375, in run
for row in itertools.islice(rows, self.chunk_size)]
File "C:\Users\simon\AdviceDataMart\lib\site-
packages\luigi\contrib\sqla.py", line 363, in rows
with self.input().open('r') as fobj:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'open'
```

I am not sure what is causing this and am not able to easily debug a luigi pipeline. I am not sure if this has to do with implementation of the run method or the output method?